# How to use regex to replace the string

Tags: java, regex, string

In java language,

How to use the regular expression to deal with the string

```
$.store.book[Random(1,9)].title
```

and replace the part of `Random(1,9)` to a real random number between `1` to `9`?

So basically, the result string will like `$.store.book[3].title` or `$.store.book[5].title`

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: I've given you some hints below, but please post the code you have so far, describe the problem you are having with it, and tell us how you've tried to solve it.

Comment: Can Random(1,9) be other ranges? I missed that part if so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression to capture arbitrary numbers would be (see **[online demo](http://ideone.com/0tXFNu)** here):

```
String input= "$.store.book[Random(1,9)].title";
System.out.println("Input: "+ input);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)Random\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)(?=\\])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String output = input;
if(m.find()) {
    int min = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
    int max = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
    int rand = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    output = output.substring(0, m.start()) + rand + output.substring(m.end());
}
System.out.println("Output: "+ output );
```

Example output:

```
Input: $.store.book[Random(1,9)].title
Output: $.store.book[6].title
```

### As a utility method:

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/5pxaxE) for code below.

```
public static String replaceRandom(String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[)Random\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)(?=\\])");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    String output = input;
    if (m.find()) {
        int min = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        int max = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
        int rand = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
        output = output.substring(0, m.start()) +rand+ output.substring(m.end());
    }
    return output;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("(1,9): "
                        + replaceRandom("$.store.book[Random(1,9)].title"));
    System.out.println("(1,999): "
                        + replaceRandom("$.store.book[Random(1,999)].title"));
    System.out.println("(50,200): "
                        + replaceRandom("$.store.book[Random(50,200)].title"));
}
```

Example output:

```
(1,9): $.store.book[4].title
(1,999): $.store.book[247].title
(50,200): $.store.book[71].title
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of would be using String.replace():

```
String str = "$.store.book[Random(1,9)].title";
str = str.replace("Random(1,9)", String.valueOf((int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1)));        
System.out.println(str);
```

Sample output being:

```
$.store.book[7].title
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,but i need to say the Random(1,9) is not invariable, The string should like "$.store.book[Random(a,b)].title",which a and b are different integer in every time.

Comment: gotcha, try to make that clear next time!  in that case, I think @acdcjunior has what you need :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this in three steps.

First you will have to find the "Random(1,9)" string. You can use a regular expression with capture groups to parse out the value range. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html.

Next you will have to generate your random number.

Finally you can use [`String.replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to replace the string with the number you've generated.

If you want to support multiple occurrences per string, repeat that until there are none left.

Edit: That said, if your range is *always* 1 to 9, Jlewis071's answer is sufficient and straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*Random\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    int min = matcher.group(1);
    int max = matcher.group(2);
    int newInt = rnd.nextInt(max-min+1) + min;
    str = str.replaceFirst("Random\\([^)]+\\)",String.valueOf(newInt));
    matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
}
```

And I probably messed up the regexes... and I see acdcjunior just posted it all, complete with an online IDE to verify it.  So I'll post my answer anyway so people appreciate my effort!  But his answer is error free for sure, and along the same lines :)  Then again, mine does repeat the replacement throughout the entire string, as suggested by other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.replace();`

Example to suit your requirement:

```
   String data = "$.store.book[Random(1,9)].title";
    Random random = new Random();

    // Replace the sub-string
    String replacedData = data.replace("Random(1,9)", String.valueOf(random.nextInt() / 10000));
    System.out.println(replacedData); // after replacement
```